# PHP get MySQL Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to build a PHP class which allows me to retrieve the names of all columns of a certain MySQL Database.

Suppose I had the following strucutre:

| ID | Name | Surname | Age | Sex |

My script should provide an array as:

```
0 => ID
1 => Name
2 => Surname
3 => Age
4 => Sex
```

Ideas? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable");
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
DESCRIBE TableName
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html), e.g. (using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo)) :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        table_name=:tablename
        AND table_schema=:databasename
');
$stmt->execute( array(':tablename'=>'foo', ':databasename'=>'bar') );
```